# What happens to Popen object if caller program ends

Tags: python

I have a Python interactive console program that calls a `subprocess` using `Popen`

What happens to subprocess if I exit the interactive program that submitted the subprocess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subprocess will terminate along with the parent **unless** the subprocess became a daemon and detached from it's parent.

See: [How Linux Process Life Cycle Works – Parent, Child, and Init Process](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/07/linux-process-life-cycle/) which is a pretty good explanation on the life-cycle of processes (*at least on LInux/UNIX*).